# use copy constructor when move constructor is declared but private

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor

Say a given class `A` is defined with a public copy constructor and a private move constructor. If a function `f` returns an object of type `A`, and `f` is used to initialize a local instance of variable of type `A`, then by default (since the value returned is a `rvalue`) the compiler will try to use the move constructor. I believed it is sensible to expect the compiler to use the copy constructor once it detects that the move constructor is private, however to my surprise I received a compiler error stating that the move constructor is private. My question is as follows, given the following code:

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class A
 {

    friend A f();

 public:
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy\n"; }


 private:
    A() {}
    A(A&&) { cout << "move\n"; }
 };

 A f()
 {
    A a;
    return a;
 }

 int main()
 {
    A a = f();
 }
```

How can I change the code (without changing A or f) so that I could initialize the variable in main using the copy constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the class since it's not sensible.

Alternatively derive from the class or wrap it.

If you just want a quick hack you can do

```
template< class Type >
Type& tempref( Type&& t ) { return t; }
```

then do

```
A a = tempref( f() )
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: @LucDanton: what on Earth do you think you're gaining by using a comma expression. plus, why do you think something must be done about `f`; maybe you didn't notice that `f` is a `friend`?

Answer (score 1):

The overload resolution is performed first, to select a function to call.

Access check is performed as a later step, checking if the selected function/constructor is possible to call.

This is done on purpose, so a private function is not called (because it *is* private). Having the compiler select another function to call in that case would not be productive.

Comment: So.., to answer the question, it's not possible?

Comment: Not possible. If the move constructor is made private, that indicates that we don't want to (publically) construct from an rvalue. To select the second best match when the best match is private, is not part of the language.